# Portfolio Optimization with budget constraint

Tags: probability, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm having trouble replicating the result from the article *Loss Aversion with Multiple Investment Goals* written by Enrico G. De Giorgi (2011), the article can be downloaded [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1448627).

First consider the choice function proposed by Kahneman and Tversky in prospect theory

$$ u(x) =  
\begin{cases}
\beta^+ x^\alpha, & x > 0 \\
-\beta^-(-x)^\alpha, & x \leq 0
\end{cases} $$

where $\beta^+$ and $\beta^-$ characterize loss aversion.

The main optimization problem is

\begin{cases}
\text{max}_{W_T} & E[u(W_T- \overline W)] \\
\text{such that: } & E[\xi_T W_T] \leq \xi_0 W_0 \\ 
&W_T \geq 0 \\
\end{cases}
where $W_0$ is the initial wealth, $W_T$ is the wealth at time horizon T, $\overline W$ is the goal wealth and $\xi$ is the pricing kernel, i.e. stochastic discount factor ($\xi_0 = 1$).

**I have two problems:**

1. Determine the optimal Lagrange multiplier, y, when applying Lagrange relaxation to this optimization problem ($y\geq 0$).
2. I don't understand the stochastic discount factor, $\xi_T$.

The Lagrange relaxation mentioned in the $\underline{\text{first problem}}$ (after some algebra) leads to the following equation representing the lagrange multiplier y:

$${ y = \left(\frac{\xi_0 W_0 - \overline W E[\xi_T]}{(\alpha \beta^+)^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}} E\left[\xi_T^{\frac{\alpha}{\alpha-1}}\right]} \right)^{(\alpha -1)}}$$

and since $y \geq 0$ implies that $\xi_0 W_0$ > $\overline W E[\xi_T]$, which leads to the second problem.

Regarding the $\underline{\text{second problem}}$; if $W_T$ is discounted with discount factor $e^{-r(T-t)}$ and fulfills the budget constraint it is obvious that the terminal wealth $W_T$ can be achieved by simply putting the wealth into a bank account with rate $r$. If this constraint has to be statisfied then one cannot achieve a goal more ambitious than a payoff with rate $r$.

Best regards,
Will